# print three lines after the matching pattern using regular expression in Python

Tags: python

Dear python community,

I want to print three lines after matching pattern in python (printing 
the matching line is easy, e.g. by using re.match(r'(.*)match(.*)', pattern)).

How to do it in python? The equivalent operation can be performed using "grep -A3 "pattern" filename".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are iterating over the lines, I would use something like this

```
i = 0
for line in lines:
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        i = 4
    if i > 0:
        print line
        i -= 1
```